# cat >/path/to/file <<EOF drops some paste content, also patch <<EOF too. Why?

Tags: shell, terminal, copy-paste

From time to time I like to use `cat >/etc/configfile <<EOF` thing, and paste content, then send `EOF` that will flush it into file. Its good with one or two lines, but when there's more of them, some of content is missing, some extra newlines are added and so one. Same goes if I use `patch <<EOF`, even with a simple patch with less than 2000 characters in total.

I suspect my terminal (urxvt) to do something wrong, It paste the content extreme fast but miss something, when I use mintty from cygwin, its slow as hell but not a single line is skipped. Also, if I enter Vim and paste it there, nothing is missed. The shell does not matter, happens on zsh, bash and ash.

Comment: It's called a here doc. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: Possibly the pasted text contains backticks or dollars. Use `<<\EOF`

Comment: A simpler way to do this is to `cat >/etc/configfile`, then paste, then hit CTRL+D to finish.  That way the shell doesn't get involved.

Answer (score 5):

I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Your terminal emulator may have a limit on the size of paste buffers, but repeated newlines, if you really have them, sounds like a bug.

Are you sure that you're taking the shell processing into account? In a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) delimited with `<<EOF`, the characters `$` and `` ` `` are interpreted by the shell as the start of a variable substitution or command substitution. So for example, if your selection contains

```
value=$PATH
more=$stuff stuff
hello=`ls`
```

then pasting it followed by `EOF` results in a file containing something like

```
value=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
more= stuff
hello=hello.txt
world.txt
```

To avoid these substitutions, tell the shell to interpret the here document content literally by quoting the here document marker (`cat <<'EOF'` or `cat <<\EOF` or `cat <<"EOF"` or any other variation).

Make sure that you're pasting the selection you intend. [X11 has multiple selections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#Clipboard); old-fashioned X11 applications where copying is automatic upon selection use the PRIMARY selection, whereas new-style X11 applications with a separate copy command use the CLIPBOARD selection.

The solution to your problem is not to paste, but to use a program such as [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) or [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) to copy the selection to a file. For the PRIMARY selection:

```
xclip -o >/etc/configfile
xclip -o | patch
xsel >/etc/configfile
xsel | patch
```

For the CLIPBOARD selection, call `xclip -selection clipboard` or to `xsel -b`.

Comment: There's no special char, like 300 lines of `up ip addr add XXX/YY dev bond0` and after something like 200 it starts dropping, adding enters etc. I will try without <<EOF to check whatever that helps and reports back.